# Basic-slider, change slidename

Tags: jquery

I'm actually use basic-slider.com. 
I'd prefer to have a figcaption as the link, instead of the title of the img.

```
<li>
  <figcaption>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    Exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
  </figcaption>
  <img src="img/exemples/index-diapo2.jpg" title="Titre de la photo1"/>
</li>
```

How can I change the slidename ?

> slidename = $(slide).find('img').attr('title'),

I tried slidename = $(slide).find('figcaption'), but it doesn't work...

Thank you !

Comment: What's `slide` in your JS snippet?

Comment: You want to change the image title?

Comment: That's not valid HTML. `<figcaption>` must be inside a `<figure>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I note Figcaption and figure, thank you.
Instead of the title of the image, I'd prefer the link.
You can referrer at this JS : http://www.basic-slider.com

```
$.each($slides, function(key, slide){
var slidenum    = key + 1,
slidename   = $(slide).find('img').attr('title'),
gotoslide   = key + 1;

if(settings.animtype === 'slide'){
gotoslide = key + 2;
}
var marker = $('<li><a href="#">'+ slidename +'</a></li>');
```

Thank you